# Why can I not deregister my style and script on custom post type?

Tags: plugins, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, scripts

I have a website where I have a custom post type with some single pages attached to it.

**Problem:** I can't deregister the scripts and styles on my custom post type single pages.

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );

function my_deregister_javascript() {
   if (is_page(array(20720, 38881))) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'basic-comment-quicktags' );
     }
        elseif (is_home()) {     
        wp_deregister_script( 'theme-my-login-ajax' );
     }

     elseif (is_singular( 'name-of-my-custom-post-type' )) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'incom-js');
     }

        elseif (is_page(array(alfabet-page))) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'wp-favroite-posts' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'basic-comment-quicktags' );
     }
```

So you can see that I am using it like this:

```
 elseif (is_singular( 'name-of-my-custom-post-type' )) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'incom-js');
 }
```

Yet this does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How exactly it's not working? But have you tried using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook? And you may also need to call `wp_dequeue_script()` before `wp_deregister_script()`.

Comment: I tried everything, yes... but I can't get it to remove it from my custom post type.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry for the delay.. So did you get it to work?